# unable to overwrite kendo treeview 'Loading' messages in Asp.net MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview

How to update the default "Loading..." message in kendo treeview inside razor cshtml. I am using Kendo api 2014.1.416

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView().Name("ProductTree")
.DataSource(d => d
    .Model(m => m
        .Id("ProductId")
        .HasChildren("Categories"))
.Read(r => r.Action("_ProductTree", "Home")))
.DataTextField("ProductName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `.Messages(...)` configurator:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView().Name("ProductTree")
    .Messages(p => p.Loading("..."))
    ....
```

Comment: Gene -thanks!! but I am unable to set messages, when I try to do so it says **"TreeviewBuilder doe not contain definition for Messages..."**

Comment: @sureshj looks like u need update kendo for latest version

Comment: @sureshj possible that your kendo has message configurator at client side (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#configuration-messages), but not implemented in mvc yet, so you can try create treeview control with only javascript